# The Currency Converter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, converters, currency

I am trying to complete this exercise:

> 1. Ask the user how much money they have.
> 2. Next, ask them what currency they have
> 3. Finally, ask them what they want to convert it into
> 4. Convert the currency to the requested output
> 5. Print a nice alert message with the value in the other currency
> 6. Your code must use a minimum of two functions.
> 7. One function should calculate the conversion.
> 8. One function should print the alert message with the converted currency and the currency name.
>
> Hint - It probably makes sense to use two conversion functions. One
> function to convert from any currency into USD and another to convert
> from USD into anything other currency.

Here is my code:

When I run the code in my browser, nothing happens.
I'm not to true if I'm calculating the conversion right and when I run this nothing prints out.

I fixed the problem so it's running now but I'm still not getting the function converting part

```
'use strict';
let money = Number(prompt("How much money do you have?."));
let moneyCurrency = prompt("What currency are you using?.");
let currencysys = prompt("What currency do you want to convert it to? EUR, JPY, GBP, USD, or  BRL");


function convertCurrency(currency, currencySystem) {
  if (currencySystem === 'JPY' || currencySystem === 'jpy') {
    return convertJPYtoUSD(currency);
  } 
  else if (currencySystem  === 'Eur' || currencySystem  === 'eur') {
    return convertEurtoUSD(currency);
  }  
  else if (currencySystem  === 'GBP'|| currencySystem  === 'gbp') {
    return convertGBPtoUSD(currency);
  }
  else if ( currencySystem  === 'BRL'|| currencySystem  === 'brl') {
    return convertBRLtoUSD(currency);
  }
}

function convertJPYtoUSD(JPY) {
  return  (JPY * 0.91);
}

function printCurrencyMessage(convertedCurrency, currencysys,round) {
  if (round === undefined || isNaN(Number(round))) {
    round = 0;
  }
}

console.log("The converted currency is "+currencySystem + ".");
```

I having a bit of trouble, The math code isn't right 100GBP to JPY should be 19,103.08 but I'm getting something completely different

```js
'use strict';
let money = Number(prompt("How much money do you have?."));
let moneyCurrency = prompt("What currency are you using?.");
let currencysys = prompt("What currency do you want to convert it to? EUR, JPY, GBP, USD, or  BRL");



let currentExchange = {
  "USD": 1,
  "EURO": 0.91,
  "JPY": 124.17,
  "GBP": 0.65,
  "BRL": 3.51,
}

let currentExchanges = currentExchange[currency];

function convertCurrency(currencyNeeded, moneyAmount) {
  let exchange_value = moneyAmount * exchange_factor
  return exchange_value
}

function convertCurrency(currencyNeeded, moneyAmount) {
  let exchange_factor = currentExchange[currencyNeeded];
  let exchange_value = moneyAmount / exchange_factor
  let value = moneyAmount * exchange_factor
  console.log("The converted amount is $ " + (exchange_value.toFixed(2)) + "in " + currencyNeeded + ".");

  return exchange_value
};

convertCurrency(currencyNeeded, moneyAmount);
```

Comment: Please include your actual code, not just a picture of it. Also describe your problem.

Comment: when i try to add my code it doesn't work and Im not to true if im doing the  calculate the conversion right and when i run this nothing prints out

Comment: How do you run your script? Why can you not copy the code here?

Comment: i just add the code, I had to add the code piece by piece

Comment: The code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ebmbpk71/  . Where you expect your code to be printed? Have you checked your printer?

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to print it out when the function converted the currency.

Comment: It is more precise to say that the first lines may run, but the code is definitely wrong (and incomplete). How Do You Run Your Script?

Comment: I guess my run my script from my browser, html and text editor sorry if i sound stupid but i'm new to this

Comment: I was trying to test run the first currency entered but nothing happen

Comment: So you have a `<script>` tag inside your html, is that it? Maybe you have the path wrong. You must open your Developer Tools for  your browser (e.g. Tools > Web developer > Web console in Firefox). It will tell you what errors it finds, and the `console.log` statement will also show up there. Also if you have HTML code, also put it here. Use indentation to format text as code here.

Comment: Yes, sir!!  The error i keep getting is  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input and I dont have html code its a blank page

Comment: okay, I fix the problem so its running now

Comment: okay, I fix the problem so it's running now but I'm still not getting the function converting part

Comment: also my console log isn't working

Answer (score 0):

**TDLR;**

You are trying to alert a variable that is not defined.

[image]

I would suggest you have your function return your value for you. Something like:

```
console.log("The converted currency is "+ convertToCurrency(moneyCurrency, currencysys + ".");
```

**Explanation and digging deeper**

Your signature

```
function convertCurrency(currency, currencySystem) {...
```

creates a local variable "currencySystem" that cannot be referenced outside of the functions scope. Hence, currencySystem is a local variable to that function.

Some general code/architecture suggestions:

Make variable names more meaningful and consistent.

Create a hashmap/object with all of your currency conversion ratios and use a single function to do the mathematical conversion. IE:

```
var currencies = {
    usd: {
        conversion: 1,
    },
    eur: {
        conversion: .89
    },
    ...
};

function convertCurrency(fromCurrency, toCurrency, amount) {

    // ... not the best at thinking of the algorithm. Suggestions?
    // perhaps normalize fromCurrency to the dollar, then convert to toCurrency since I believe the dollar is the base/universal currency
};

var convertedCurrency = convertCurrency("USD", "EUR", 20.50);

alert("The converted amount is" + convertedCurrency);
```

If you need multiple functions as a requirement, splitting out into each currency conversion isn't a horrible idea, but seems like a bit much overhead.

Here is a final working solution:

```
'use strict';
let amount = Number(prompt("How much money do you have?."));
let currentCurrency = prompt("What currency are you using?");
let desiredCurrency = prompt("What currency do you want to convert it to? EUR, JPY, GBP, USD, or  BRL");

var currencyRates = {
    "USD": 1,
  "EUR": .8,
  "JPY": .7,
  "XXX": 5
};

function convertCurrency(currentCurrency, desiredCurrency, amount) {
  var currentRate = currencyRates[currentCurrency];
  var desiredRate = currencyRates[desiredCurrency];

  var USDAmount = amount * currentRate;
  var convertedAmount = USDAmount / desiredRate;

  return convertedAmount; // I think this is the right algorithm :/
}



var convertedCurrencyAmount = convertCurrency(currentCurrency, desiredCurrency, amount);

alert ("Converted: " + convertedCurrencyAmount);
```